# How to find top 3 values in amount, based on another column by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

[image]

- A, B, C, D, E are games. There are 80 different games
- This dataframe has 5,000 rows

How can I list top 3 games, in terms of amount?

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Answer (score 2):

First use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for lists to scalars, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last get top3 by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html), because `value_counts` sorting by default:

```
top3 = df.explode('Games').drop_duplicates(['Games','Room'])['Games'].value_counts().head(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode your `Games` columns (if `Games` contains real Python list) then drop duplicates (according your side notes) and use `value_counts` with different parameters according to what you want:

1. Top 3 for all rooms:

```
>>> df.explode('Games') \
      .drop_duplicates(['Games', 'Rooms']) \
      .value_counts('Games').head(3)
Games
A    2
B    2
C    2
dtype: int64
```

2. Top 3 per room:

```
>>> df.explode('Games') \
      .drop_duplicates(['Games', 'Rooms']) \
      .value_counts(['Games', 'Rooms']).head(3)
Games  Rooms
A      North    1
       West     1
B      East     1
dtype: int64
```

Setup:

```
data = {'Games': [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['A', 'C'], ['D']],
        'Rooms': ['West', 'East', 'East', 'North', 'South']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output:
       Games  Rooms
0  [A, B, C]   West
1     [B, D]   East
2     [B, E]   East
3     [A, C]  North
4        [D]  South
```